# Go, extract days out of byte array

Tags: string, go, byte

I have a byte array containing the output of an Active Directory call. I want to parse this and extract the amount of days until my account expires. Now I'm wondering: what's the best way to extract `22-4-2016 11:05:26` (so the value after `Password Expires`)?

```
[]byte(`The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain local.nl.bol.com.

User name                    bla
Full Name                    bla bla
Comment
User's comment
Country code                 (null)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password expires             22-4-2016 11:05:26
Password changeable          13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script                 bla.bat
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   31-3-2016 7:59:29

Logon hours allowed          All

The command completed successfully.`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strings.TrimSpace`, `strings.Index` and referring to related stackoverflow answers, I got a working solution and please find working code below:-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func CToGoString(c []byte) string {
    n := -1
    for i, b := range c {
        if b == 0 {
            break
        }
        n = i
    }
    return string(c[:n+1])
}

func main() {

    s := []byte(`The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain local.nl.bol.com.

User name                    bla
Full Name                    bla bla
Comment
User's comment
Country code                 (null)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password expires             22-4-2016 11:05:26
Password changeable          13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script                 bla.bat
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   31-3-2016 7:59:29

Logon hours allowed          All

The command completed successfully.`)

d := CToGoString(s)
    len := len("Password expires")
i := strings.Index(d, "Password expires")
j := strings.Index(d, "Password changeable")
chars := d[i+len:j]
fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(chars))
}
```

Have posted code to playground: http://play.golang.org/p/t0Xjd04-pi

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by converting the []byte into a string and then using the strings package to find and extract the value and finally parsing it with time.Parse to convert the string to a time that you can work with.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    line := data[strings.Index(data, "Password expires"):strings.Index(data, "Password changeable")]
    date := strings.TrimSpace(strings.TrimPrefix(line, "Password expires"))
    fmt.Println(date)
    pDate, err := time.Parse("02-1-2006 03:04:05", date)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(pDate)
}

var data = string([]byte(`The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain local.nl.bol.com.

User name                    bla
Full Name                    bla bla
Comment
User's comment
Country code                 (null)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password expires             22-4-2016 11:05:26
Password changeable          13-3-2016 11:05:26
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script                 bla.bat
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   31-3-2016 7:59:29

Logon hours allowed          All

The command completed successfully.`))
```

On the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DKOd9es2Lr).